# Can I safely close port 53?

Tags: linux

On a vanilla ubuntu 10.04 install running `nmap` shows the following:

```
22/tcp  open  ssh
53/tcp  open  domain
...
```

It seems that `bind9` is running and port 53 is open. I'd like to close as many ports as possible to harden the system, but I'm not sure about this one.

Does it affect the DNS system if I close port 53, or is it only required if I actually host a DNS server?

Can I safely close it?

Comment: What does secondary or slave mean, is it repeater (extender).

Comment: Where do you read secondary/slave?

Comment: DNS requests are sent from a random port above 1023, so it won't hurt DNS  to close the receive port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is required only if you are hosting a DNS server, as primary/secondary/slave etc. If that is not the case, simply permanently stop the service and make sure incoming connection to port 53 is closed at the firewall level.

Comment: Most likely you don't have to do anything at "the firewall level" after simply stopping the nameserver.